# What specific experiments would psychologists perform in a school?

Tags: psychology, dystopia

It's the future America: the US is ruled by an elite band of Psychologists, who function as the political and moral leaders of the country. The Psychologists wish to institute a system of universal labeling. In the proposed system, upon becoming of age, every citizen would receive a personal "label," or area of character perfection. The idea is that this system would get rid of mental health stigma, because every single person would be assigned a course of therapy and/or treatment.

**The problem:** imposing the system on the public while it's still in its developmental stages is bad. The public might reject it. It might fail. People could get angry. They might even (gasp!) not vote to re-elect the current leaders.

---

**The solution:** the Psychologists found a series of schools which they intend to use as [field experiments](https://methods.sagepub.com/reference/the-sage-encyclopedia-of-communication-research-methods/i5632.xml).

> Field experiments are studies using experimental design that occur in a natural setting. Researchers examine how the manipulation of at least one independent variable leads to a change in a dependent variable in the context of the natural environment.

They replicate their Labeling system on this local level, and then study its effects on the students. This is still bad. The system is untested. Collecting data on minors might be unethical. Students could suffer lasting emotional harm. But at least the school's activities are shod in secrecy. If things go wrong, the Psychologists can emerge with their popularity intact. Probably. To avoid legal issues, parents and teachers are required to sign a consent form. In return, they receive a monetary bonus and the potential for fame.

Here's how the school works: Every student *and* teacher is assigned a Label. One of the teachers has thrift syndrome - she is way too careful with spending. One student has bigorexia - the Psychologists think he is too obsessed with bodybuilding. And so on... They are given customized treatment protocols which they are expected to follow. The Psychologists monitor them closely to ensure compliance and observe the effects of treatment on the student or teacher.

In additional to the Labeling, the curriculum is highly controlled, with a strong emphasis on inclusion. There is an honors society for students who show potential to become future Psychologists (they embody traits of humility, empathy, confidence). The students are given personality and IQ tests so that the Psychologists can see how these factors affect conformity to the system. In short, the students are monitored constantly, during social and academic activities in and out of school. There are also frequent labs, which are controlled settings in which the Psychologists can assign activities and collect data.

---

**The question:** what kind of psychological experiments might be performed on the students in a lab class in order to collect data? The psychologists can set up the room, include props, etc. Assume they have access to any resources they need, and that ethics are not a concern unless it involves extreme physical harm. Ideas could be based on past experiments. I'm looking specifically for a list of experiments that could be performed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141691/discussion-on-question-by-theresa-kay-what-specific-experiments-would-psychologi).

Answer (score 2):

**A frame challenge.**

Right from the get-go, the idea of 'labels' is troublesome.

Albert Ellis, back in the 1950's, came up with his [ABC theory](https://www.healthline.com/health/abc-model). Unfortunately, since then, it has been sanitized, bastardized, and obscured. I learned the original concept, when it first came out. It needs to be linked to [Cognitive Dissonance](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/basics/cognitive-dissonance), which came out at approximately the same time.

Side bar 1: Cognitive Dissonance describes the human reaction and conflict when contradictory labels, and associated emotional tags, are assigned to the same stimulus by two people.

Side bar 2: The extremist leaders on both sides of the continuum, and the advertising industry, have mastered the original concept admirably. Then, they buried it.

The original idea goes as thus:

First, the person observes objects or actions. (Eats something distasteful). A primitive value reaction is made by the lower brain generated by and applied to this stimulus (fight, flight, ignore). These are gut emotional reactions of fear, anger, pleasure, negative avoid, positive approach. They are linked the the visceral adrenergic system.

Then, the person forms a concept, or 'label', of the original stimulus. Concept formation is a basic human trait. (vegetable). The original visceral, emotional reaction is applied to the concept, or label. (vegetables are distasteful, I hate them)

Thereafter, any object or action that receives the same label has the same emotional tag attached to it, regardless of the actual reality of the stimulus. (all vegetables are yucky).

Consider early humans. Even though primitive rational thought was evolving, it had its advantages and disadvantages. It takes processing time. When they were out on the hunt, there was generally no time for rational thought. Life or death depended on immediate reactions. You see a large predator, that predator attacks you, you barely escape. So they form a general concept and label it 'predator', and attach the reaction 'scary stuff, RUN'.

Thereafter, when out on the hunt, and they see something different from the original animal, but close enough to be labeled 'predator', they do not wait around long enough to rationalize and study if that new animal is friendly, foe, or neutral, they treat it as the label, and RUN. They react to the concept, the label, the emotional tag, not the stimulus.

The concept labelling is also done immediately, without regard for the suitability to the stimulus.  They did not have the luxury of a scientific study of the new stimulus, analyzing its characteristics, evaluating it, and then categorizing it under a label. The process is immediate, done without rational thought, at the primitive mind level. The emotional tag of the label is firmly established in the mind, and is simply transferred to the new stimulus. No rational analysis of the new stimulus is necessary nor, indeed, done. The label is made, the label sticks.

The process is extremely potent when the situation is already hyped up, super-emotional, visceral, like at a mass rally where our herd instinct is predominant. It is not so effective under quiet, contemplative, reflective non-stressful conditions. This has been strongly established in the research of emotional learning and neural psychology. When stressed out, rational thought goes out the window and this "stimulus - emotional tag - action" takes over at the visceral level.

Unfortunately, once a label is established and applied to a new stimulus, it is very, very difficult for the mind to remove it. Once something is labeled 'vegetable', no amount of coaxing will convince the child to try it.

So generally, the extremists and the advertising industry uses this extensively. This was most evident in the last American election. Trump would label an adversary, and assign a negative judgement ON THE LABEL. It did not matter what the emotional connotation on the label was previously, Trump made sure the label had a negative connotation when he applied it. In fact, by virtue of Trump attaching the label, it automatically received a negative tag. Thereafter, Trump would refer to the label, not the person. And the label would be transferable to any other adversary. The adversary that was so labeled would take the negative baggage of the original person, and of the label, regardless of the suitability.

And Trump used it extensively in emotionally charged rallies where the followers were hyped up on adrenalin.

Although Trump made very effective use of this technique, he is not alone in using it. He did not invent it, nor did he develop it. He just perfected it. He is a contemporary master of the technique, able to use it efficiently and effectively, and created a lot of pertinent well-known modern examples that illustrate it.

It is a natural process of the human mind. We do it all the time, and preventing us from doing it is impossible. It is done at such a low level of human processing. It was indeed a vital step in insuring our survival when we started to think rationally. Immediate action-reaction to counter "Hmmm, I wonder, let me think..."

So trying to use labels to eliminate prejudices or preconceptions is futile. In fact, it will have exactly the opposite effect. It directly leads to, and in fact is the basis of, racism and prejudices. The labels will form a generalized concept, that will, by human nature, be tagged with some emotional judgement. Thereafter, anything that has the label attached to it will be treated with the same emotional tag as the concept, not the properties of the new 'thing'.

The end result will be that your humans go around attaching positive and negative tags to labels and then attaching these labels to other people to suit their objectives.

Consider the recent movement to capitalize the '**B**' in '**B**lack' and the '**W**'  in '**W**hite' in America. These two words have now become labels used as identifiers for a specific group, with specific emotional judgements attached, and specific characteristics. A person can be labeled 'Black" even if they are any skin color BUT black (I refuse to accept that Obama's skin color was black, and that under no rational thought process could he be considered black, but labeling him as capital-B Black is another matter altogether) and thereafter be lumped in with the general characteristics of the concept 'Black', done with specific intent and purpose, to identify them as part of a well defined and tagged sub-set of humans. In point of fact, a person whose skin tone is other than white can now be labeled 'White', and being labeled 'White' no longer demands that you have a white skin tone. 'White' is now a label for a concept, not a genetic racially identifiable group.

**TL:DR**

The process of labeling people will have, as unintended consequences, the result of enhancing stereotypes, prejudices, and stigma, not reducing it.

See also [Jane Elliott’s experiment](https://exploringyourmind.com/blue-eyes-and-brown-eyes-the-jane-elliott-experiment/)

> Blue Eyes and Brown Eyes: The Jane Elliott Experiment
>
> Jane Elliott, a teacher and anti-racism activist, performed a direct
> experiment with the students in her classroom. She told them that
> people with brown eyes were better than people with blue eyes. She
> also made the brown-eyed students put construction paper armbands on
> the blue-eyed students.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As I mentioned in the comments above, my story is about exactly your point. The psychologists try to get rid of stigma, but what happens is stigma over labels. Society begins thinking in terms of labels and classifying people based on labels.

Answer (score 0):

### Prisoner's dilemma

- [Prisoner's dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoner%27s_dilemma)

> Two members of a criminal gang are arrested and imprisoned. Each prisoner is in solitary confinement with no means of speaking to or exchanging messages with the other. The police admit they don't have enough evidence to convict the pair on the principal charge. They plan to sentence both to two years in prison on a lesser charge. Simultaneously, the police offer each prisoner a Faustian bargain.

In this setup, police offer the prisoners the opportunity to confess in exchange for a lighter sentence. If both betray the other, each serves a sentence. If one betrays while one remains silent, the one who confesses gets a longer sentences and the other goes free. If neither confesses, they each receive the shortest sentences possible.

This could be set up using other rewards/consequences, and used to evaluate loyalty to friends, self-preservation, or rational thought.

### Stanford prison experiment

- A moderation of the [Stanford prison experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanford_prison_experiment)

> The Stanford prison experiment (SPE) was a psychological experiment conducted in the summer of 1971. It was a two-week simulation of a prison environment that examined the effects of situational variables on participants' reactions and behaviors.

This was a super unethical experiment in which participants were randomly selected to be either guards or prisoners. They each fell into their roles, so the prisoners behaved as such and the guards treated them cruelly, despite knowing that the prisoners were innocent and were their equals.

This could be set up by putting some students in positions of authority and having others listen to them. It could be used to observe how students act in positions of authority or relate to authority.

### Milgram experiment

- A variation of the [Milgram experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milgram_experiment)

> The Milgram experiment(s) on obedience to authority figures were a series of social psychology experiments conducted by Yale University psychologist Stanley Milgram. They measured the willingness of study participants... to obey an authority figure who instructed them to perform acts conflicting with their personal conscience. Participants were led to believe that they were assisting an unrelated experiment, in which they had to administer electric shocks to a "learner". These fake electric shocks gradually increased to levels that would have been fatal had they been real.

In this experiment, participants felt compelled to give shocks to a stranger because they were told by authority to do so. In a school setup, they could have authority tell the students to do things to other students that they feel uncomfortable with (betray them cheating, for example) to see how they respond.